# Can't attach terminal to a running container in docker

Tags: terminal, websocket, docker

I'm giving a try to :

https://github.com/rainforestapp/Docker-Terminal

I have turned docker to listen tcp; so i have successfully opened port 4242 (-d -H=tcp://localhost:4242); I run a bare container:

```
docker pull dhrp/sshd
```

And then ran:

```
docker run -d -t dhrp/sshd
```

I can see the container running; but when I attach to it (using Docker Terminal) it shows : Session started and then nothing.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the `dhrp/sshd` image will start a ssh server. There is no point in attaching to it. You can ssh to it.

If you want to attach to a running container, you need to do a couple of things:

1. Start the docker daemon in TCP mode (`docker -d -H tcp://`) WARNING: Insecure.
2. Put the correct host/port in Docker-Terminal's index.html in `data-docker-terminal-host` (the port is 4243)
3. Start a container
4. Put the ID of the running container you want to attach to in `data-docker-terminal-container` still in Docker-Terminal's index.html

Comment: well thanks for the 'obvious'; if you carefully read my question i already did all that but i can't 'type' in the tty window; what process you think I should run to get an 'interactive' shell-like terminal ? that was more the point of my question.

Comment: In order to be able to 'type', you need to allocate stdin with `-i`. However, the program needs to read on it. `dhrp/sshd` won't, if you want to try something, you can try `docker run -d -i -t ubuntu bash`. It will spawn a ubuntu (12.04) container and start bash on it.

Comment: thanks I thought that I couldn't mix both '-d' and '-i' options; now that makes sense (and works).

Comment: Good :). Yes you can mix `-d` and `-i` so you can attach later with stdin. Most programs like `bash` or `cat` will close if stdin is not allocated, even in detached mode. I reverted the edits on my answer as the port IS 4243 when starting with `docker -d -H tcp://`. It can't be anything else. If you want to change, then you need to start docker with different option.

Comment: I edited my question and yes i did start on port 4242   :) Thanks